# Win32 C/C++ Reading BMP width and height from a byte array

Tags: c++, c, winapi, bitmap

I have read a BMP file into a byte array. So after looking into the answers of this question: [byte array to int c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855115/byte-array-to-int-c). Is this way of obtaining the widht and height from a [BMP information header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_.28bitmap_information_header.29) safe and correct?

```
long width, height;
memcpy(&width, &bmp[0x12], sizeof(long)); 
memcpy(&height, &bmp[0x16], sizeof(long));
```

And what problems could this approach bring?

```
long* width = (long*)(&bmp[0x12]);
long* height= (long*)(&bmp[0x16]);
```

According to [Wikipedia BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_.28bitmap_information_header.29), `0x12` is the offset of the bitmap width in pixels, and `0x16` the offset of the bitmap height in pixels.

PD. I have found this solution for [loading the bitmap from memory buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886831/win32-c-c-load-image-from-memory-buffer) but I want to keep the code simple because I only need the width, the height and the raw data of the bitmap, and I do not know if that answer is safe either.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using standart BMP lyout definition (BITMAPINFOHEADER structure) from (if you are writing for Windows in Visual Studio) wingdi.h : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318229(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DenisGladkiy Yes, but I think we will come back to the same thing: how do I fill this structure? Is this solution [loading the bitmap from memory buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886831/win32-c-c-load-image-from-memory-buffer) safe?

Comment: the "read" operation by itself is safe, because it reads fixed amount of bytes. But you must check the bytes (BITMAPINFOHEADER structure fields) you've read. For example check if the width is > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches do essentially the same thing, and both have the same fundamental problem: won't work if the host system has a different byte-order than the BMP file uses. This is always the problem with directly accessing values larger than a single byte in binary format.

The latter approach also has the additional disadvantage of possibly breaking if the host cannot do a `long` access at the resulting addresses.

In short, both "solutions" are bad. It's better to extract the value byte-by-byte and re-consititute it:

```
static uint32_t read_uint32_t(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t offset)
{
  buffer += offset;
  const uint32_t b0 = *buffer++;
  const uint32_t b1 = *buffer++;
  const uint32_t b2 = *buffer++;
  const uint32_t b3 = *buffer++;
  return (b3 << 24) | (b2 << 16) | (b1 << 8) | b0;
}
```

The above uses a smidgeon of C99 for brevity, porting it back to C89 is trivial.

Edit: the above works on *any* arcihtecture, since it's no longer doing direct accesses. Instead it assumes `buffer` contains bytes in little-endian format, which I believe is what the x86-originated BMP format always uses. So, it will work even on a big-endian machine. It also no longer does possibly mis-aligned large memory accesses, since all accesses are just byte-sized which should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `memcpy` works OK as long as `long` is a 32-bit value (I'd personally use `uint32_t` instead). The cast will work if you know the architecture that runs the code is always going to be x86.

[Good points by others about byteorder].

If you care about byteorder, then use something like:

```
uint32_t width = bmp[0x12] + (bmp[0x13] << 8) + (bmp[0x14] << 16) + (bmp[0x15] << 24);
```

and the same for length. This assumes your `bmp` values are `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches might be correct for Win32. But generally both are unsafe.  The first variant relies on `sizeof(long) == 4`.  Second relies on this too but requires correct alignment of data (which might be problem e.g. on ARM).  Both have on common that they assume a certain endianess and will show different behavior on e.g. x86 and mips.